# Java Parking Ticket Simulator

Tags: java

I have looked on here and spent some time on this and now I have hit a brick wall.
I am wokring on the Parking Ticket simulator in Java.
I am not very good at Java, but seem to have most of it working.
The only problem is that I put in a demo/test file and it gives me the same answer all the time. Even with ridiculous values.
Can someone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Thanks, All the code is below:

```
/**
 * @(#)ParkedCar.java
 *
 * ParkedCar application
 *
 * 
 * @version 3.00 2014/2/9
 */

public class ParkedCar 
{


//Define Variables

    private String CarMake;
    private String CarModel;
    private String CarColour;
    private String CarLicensePlate;
    private static int NumberOfMinutesParked;


//Define Constructors

    // NO ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
    // Set Vaules to Zero or null

    public ParkedCar()
    {
        CarMake = " ";
        CarModel = " ";
        CarColour = " ";
        CarLicensePlate = " ";
        NumberOfMinutesParked = 0;  
    }



    // CONSTRUCTOR WHICH ACCEPTS AN INPUT

    public ParkedCar(String Make,String Model,String Colour,String Reg, int NoMinsPkd)
    {
        CarMake = Make;
        CarModel = Model;
        CarColour = Colour;
        CarLicensePlate = Reg;
        NumberOfMinutesParked = NoMinsPkd;
    }


    // Use the SET Method
    // Set the variables - no needed
    public void setMake(String Make)
    {
        CarMake = Make;
    }

    public void setModel(String Model)
    {
        CarModel = Model;
    }

    public void setColour(String Colour)
    {
        CarColour = Colour;
    }

    public void setReg(String Reg)
    {
        CarLicensePlate = Reg;
    }

    public void setNoMinsPkd(int NoMinsPkd)
    {
        NumberOfMinutesParked = NoMinsPkd;
    }

    // USE THE GET METHODS
    // Get the Variables - used to read in values
    public String getMake()
    {
        return CarMake;
    }
    public String getModel()
    {
        return CarModel;
    }
    public String getColour()
    {
        return CarColour;
    }
    public String getReg()
    {
        return CarLicensePlate;
    }
    public static int getNoMinsPkd()
    {
        return NumberOfMinutesParked;
    }

    // USE THE TO STRING METHODS
    // Output to a Sting 
    public String toString() 
        {

            String PkdCar = "Make: " + CarMake
                + "\nModel: " + CarModel
                + "\nColor: " + CarColour
                + "\nLicense Plate: " + CarLicensePlate;
            return PkdCar;
        }

}
```

Then

```
/**
 * @(#)ParkingMeter.java
 *
 * ParkedCar application
 *
 * 
 * @version 4.00 2014/2/9
 */


public class ParkingMeter
{

    //Define Variables
    private static int MinsPurchsed; 

    //Define Constructors

    // NO ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
    // Set Vaules to Zero or null
    public ParkingMeter()
    {
    //  MinsPurchsed = 0;
    }

    // CONSTRUCTOR WHICH ACCEPTS AN INPUT
    public ParkingMeter(int Purchased)
    {
        MinsPurchsed = Purchased;
    }

    // Use the SET Method
    // Set the variables - not needed
    public void setPurchased(int Purchased)
    {
        MinsPurchsed = Purchased;
    }

    // USE THE GET METHODS
    // Get the Variables
    public static int getPurchased()
    {
        return MinsPurchsed;
    }

    // USE THE TO STRING METHODS
    // Output to a Sting 
    public String toString() 
    {
        String MeterString = "Minutes Purchased: " + MinsPurchsed;
        return MeterString;
    }

}
```

Then

```
/**
 * @(#)GardaOfficer.java
 *
 * ParkedCar application
 *
 * 
 * @version 3.00 2014/2/9
 * @version 4.50 2014/4/13
 */

public class GardaOfficer //extends ParkedCar 
{
    // Define all the variables
    //==========================
    private String Name;
    private String BadgeNumber;
    private double Ticket;



    // Constructor to accept all the variables
    //========================================

    public GardaOfficer(String n, String num)
    {
        Name = n;
        BadgeNumber = num;

    }

    // NO ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR
    //========================

        public GardaOfficer()
    {
        Name = "";
        BadgeNumber = "";


    }

    // SET METHODS
    //===============

    public void setName(String n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }


    public void setBadgeNumber(String num)
    {
        BadgeNumber = num;
    }




    // GET METHODS
    //===============

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getBadgeNumber()
    {
        return BadgeNumber;
    }

    // TO STRING METHOD
    //=================

    public String toString() 
    {
        String GardaString = "Garda : " + this.Name
                        + "\nBadge: " + BadgeNumber
                        + "\nTicket: " + Ticket;
        return GardaString;

    }




    public ParkingTicket search(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter) 
        {
            GardaOfficer Garda = new GardaOfficer(this.Name,this.BadgeNumber);
            int time = ParkedCar.getNoMinsPkd() - ParkingMeter.getPurchased();

            if(ParkedCar.getNoMinsPkd() > ParkingMeter.getPurchased()) 
                {
                if(time <= 60) 
                    {
                        Ticket = 50;

                    }

                else 
                    {
                        Ticket = 50 + (10 * (time/60));
                    }
                }

                if(time <0)

                        return null;
                        return new ParkingTicket(car, Garda, getTicket(), time);

                    }

                public double getTicket()
                    {
                        return Ticket;
                    }

                public void setTicket(double ticket) 
                    {
                        this.Ticket = Ticket;
                    }
}
```

Then

```
/**
 * @(#)ParkingTicket.java
 *
 * ParkedCar application
 *
 * 
 * @version 4.00 2014/2/9
 */

public class ParkingTicket
{

//Define Variables
private ParkedCar Vehicle;
private GardaOfficer GuardString;
private double ParkingFine;
private int Minutes;
private double firstFine = 50;
private double moreFine = 50;

public ParkingTicket()
    {
    }

// CONSTRUCTOR WHICH ACCEPTS AN INPUT
public ParkingTicket(ParkedCar car, GardaOfficer Guard, double guyFine, int mins) 
    {

        Vehicle = car;
        GuardString = Guard;
        ParkingFine = guyFine;
        Minutes = mins;
    }

    // Use the SET Method
    // Set the variables - not needed



    // USE THE GET METHODS
    // Get the Variables
    public void getTotalFine() 
        {
            int time = ParkedCar.getNoMinsPkd() - ParkingMeter.getPurchased();

            if (time <= 60) 
                {
                    ParkingFine = firstFine;
                } 
            else 
                {
                    ParkingFine = firstFine + moreFine * (time / 60);
                }
        }

    public double getFirstFine() 
        {
            return firstFine;
        }

    public double getMoreFine() 
        {
            return moreFine;
        }

    public ParkedCar getVehicle() 
        {
            return Vehicle;
        }

    public GardaOfficer getGuardString() 
        {
            return GuardString;
        }

    public int getMinutes() 
        {
            return Minutes;
        }

    public double getFine() 
        {
            return ParkingFine;
        }


    // USE THE TO STRING METHODS
    // Output to a Sting 
    public String toString() 
        {

            String TicketString = "Fine : " + this.ParkingFine
                            + "\nMinutes: " + Minutes
                            + "\n" + Vehicle.toString()
                            + "\n" + this.getGuardString().toString();

            return TicketString;

        }
}
```

Finally

```
//This is a demo file to show the program

public class DemoCar 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            ParkedCar Test1 = new ParkedCar("BMW", "2014", "Yellow", "141D12345", 30);
            ParkingMeter parking = new ParkingMeter(50);
            GardaOfficer Murphy = new GardaOfficer("Guard Murphy", "10");
            ParkingTicket ticket = Murphy.search(Test1, parking);

        if (ticket != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(ticket.toString());
            } 
        else 
            {
                System.out.println("No ticket issued!");
            }


// A second car checked to see if it passes or not, it's over
            ParkedCar Test2 = new ParkedCar("VW", "2001", "Green", "01D321", 225);
            ParkingMeter parking2 = new ParkingMeter(200);
            ParkingTicket ticket2 = Murphy.search(Test2, parking2);

        if (ticket != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(ticket.toString());
            } 
        else 
            {
                System.out.println("No ticket issued!");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Wayyy to much code. Can you strip this down to minimal code that demonstrates the problem? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Also, check out [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). Variables should be `camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the camelCase, Thats my next thing to do. I had it all nice then changed and changed to try and get it to work. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

You're printing ticket instead of ticket2 the second time around.

Also you should always make your variables lowercase.

Comment: Thanks a million for the help! Thats the issue, i cant believe i missed it.